# complement/negation doesn't work right

Tags: c#, negation, complement

hello i wrote a small program to demonstrate the problem that i'm facing

```
long n;
n = 1;    //1=0001  //2=0010 //-2=1101

Console.WriteLine(n+" "+ ~n);
Console.WriteLine(n+~n);
```

and the output is something like this :

```
1 -2
-1
```

as i know ~ sign should give same negative number, but the number that i'm getting is all the time one more than the original number
according to following link the answer that i have to get should be same, and if i add the negation to the original number i should get 0 not another number
http://visualcsharptutorials.com/reference/converting-negative-numbers-to-binary

can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? 
i'm using .net 4.5, c#5.0, vs 2012

Comment: "as i know ~ sign should give same negative number" - Where did you get this idea?

Comment: You should read that article again, you'll see that you missed a step.

Comment: What's wrong is that you don't understand how twos-complement numbers work.  Read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system you're describing is called [ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) and it's **not** the system used in most modern environments (including C#). What is used is [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In this system, -1 is 1111, -2 is 1110, etc. That means the numbers you're getting are correct, because `~1 == -2`.